# ajaxValidation is not working when i use custom id in htmlOption Array

Tags: yii

> i need custom id eg, 'id'=>table_name  in below code.  When i remove id from htmloptions array, ajax validation works fine,  but it does no when i use id.

```
<div class="form">
<?php
 $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'data-fixer-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'onsubmit'=>"return false;",/* Disable normal form submit */
        'onkeypress'=>" if(event.keyCode == 13){ ajaxReplaceValue(event); } " /* Do ajax call when user presses enter key */
    ),
));
?>
<?php echo $form->dropDownListControlGroup($model,'table_name',$tableNames,array('id'=>'table_name','onchange'=>'getColumn(event)','class'=>'span4')); ?>
<?php echo $form->dropDownListControlGroup($model,'column_name',$columnNames,array('id'=>'column_name','class'=>'span4')); ?>
<?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'search_for',array('id'=>'search_for','placeholder'=>tTools('dataFixer','search_for'),'class'=>'span4')); ?>
<?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'replace_with',array('id'=>'replace_with','placeholder'=>tTools('dataFixer','replace_with'),'class'=>'span4')); ?>
<div class="form-actions">
    <?php
     echo CHtml::submitButton(t('common','submit'), array (
        'id'=>'dataFixerSubmitBtn',
        'class'=>'btn btn-primary',
        'identity'=>'',
        'dataFetched'=>'0',
        'onclick'=>'ajaxReplaceValue(event);'
        ));
    ?>
</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Comment: can't we give id    like 'id'=>'some_id ' inside htmlOptions array?

Answer (score -1):

> finally i got the solution. We need to prepend  Model Name  befor id as below

```
'id'=>'DataFixer_table_name'
```

where DataFixer is model name